# What’s the difference between subjuctive and indicative mood for modal verbs, when expressing possibility?

Tags: verb, subjunctive, modal-verb

It seems that both the following expressions are possible:

> Sie könnte im Büro sein.
>   Sie kann im Büro sein.
>
> Der Täter dürfte nach etwas gesucht haben, was für ihn sehr wichtig ist.
>   Der Täter darf nach etwas gesucht haben, was für ihn sehr wichtig ist.

I understand that when used to express a request, the subjunctive tense might be interpreted as being more polite. But what’s the difference here, when the modal verbs are used to express possibilities? Which one is the more common/correct usage?

(My textbook offered a sentence: “Das kann der Täter gewesen sein”, which to me would be awkward in English: “That can have been the perpetrator”, since in English the only correct way would be “That could have been the perpetrator”. This makes me quite confused.)

Comment: "since in English the only correct way would be" - are you sure "That may/might have been the perpetrator" would be incorrect?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper What I mean is that you probably can't say "That can have been". Of course "That may/might have been" is correct.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper But yeah good point, in that I don't really differentiate between may/might in this case, at least as a non-native speaker. They sound pretty much like expressing the same thing to me, only that "might" might be slightly less strong. Is the situation similar in German though?

Comment: I didn't think about that distinction; I rather wrote my comment because I would usually translate "Das kann der Täter gewesen ein." as "That may have been the perpetrator." (unless strict word-by-word adherence is required), or even using "might", if I am otherwise not sure the meaning of "may" is clearly understood as an assumption rather than a permit ("He may enter the train.") in whatever the context is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s first assume that there is no other reason that triggers the subjunctive (such as a conditional, politeness, etc., see below). In that case, one needs to distinguish between *können* and the other modal verbs:

- For ***können***, there is hardly any change of meaning whatsoever. In both, the indicative and the subjunctive II mood, this verbs expresses possibility. I would wager that the vast majority of subjunctive II uses of *können* in the German language can be replaced by the indicative without any loss of meaning whatsoever (and can confirm this from my copy-editing experiences, where this replacement was a method to squeeze some space).

  Note, however, that when expressing very low likelihood, it is more idiomatic to use the subjunctive mood, e.g.:

  > »Wie hat er das bloß bezahlt?« — »Er **könnte** im Lotto gewonnen haben.«

  The subjunctive mood is also sometimes used to express a lower likelihood than the indicative mood, but this only works when there is a comparison:

  > Sie kann in ihrer Wohnung sein; sie könnte auch im Büro sein.

  Finally, in some contexts, using the subjunctive mood for *können* avoids it being confused as meaning *to be able to* or *to have the opportunity to,* e.g.:

  > »Wie überquerst du den Fluss?« – »Ich kann schwimmen.«
  >
  > »Wie überquerst du den Fluss?« – »Ich könnte schwimmen.«

  In both cases, this can be understood as “I might swim”, but in the first case, it could also be read as “I am able to swim”.
- With **dürfen, sollen, and müssen**, using the indicative mood to express any sort of possibility has become rare and odd, except for some fixed or semi-fixed expressions. As a native speaker, I rarely ever use the indicative mood for these purposes. Take, for instance, your second example sentence:

  > Der Täter darf nach etwas gesucht haben, was für ihn sehr wichtig ist.

  I am a native speaker, and while I acknowledge that *dürfen* **can** be read as *to possibly be* or similar here, it took me quite some time to get there and feels very archaic. Instead I read it as *to be allowed to.*

Note, however, that there are often additional reasons that enforce the subjunctive mood. In some of these cases, the subjunctive modal verbs can indicate either possibility or their “regular” (non-possibility) indicative meaning:

- A conditional clause:

  > Wo mag sie nur sein? Wenn nicht Sonntag wäre, könnte sie im Büro sein.
  >
  > Ihr Drucker ist ausgefallen. Wenn nicht Sonntag wäre, könnte sie ins Büro gehen und dort drucken.

  Be aware of implicit conditional clauses:

  > Könnte er doch schwimmen! [Dann ertränke er nicht.]
  >   If only he were able to swim! [Then he would not drown.]
- Politeness:

  > Könnten Sie mir bitte das Salz reichen?
- Implying that somebody did not do something despite having the ability, opportunity, allowance:

  > Er könnte mit dem Bus fahren, aber läuft lieber.
  >
  > Sie müsste den Antrag heute einreichen, aber sie hat ihn nicht rechtzeitig fertiggestellt.

Comment: Ich würde *könnte* nie mit *kann* gleichsetzen, weil ich immer einen Unterton unausgesprochener Konditionen höre, was wahrscheinlich auch der Grund für den stärkeren Irrealis-Beigeschmack ist. Natürlich eine tolle Antwort!

Comment: @Ludi: Naja, jede Möglichkeit hat irgendwo eine unausgesprochene Kondition, und sei es: »Wenn der Zufall so will.«

Comment: Stimmt. Allerdings wird diese durch *könnte* angedeutet und durch *kann* nicht.